# How can i solve Python while loop problem?

Tags: python, while-loop

Running this code

```
letters=["cat","dog","3","gorilla","cat","cat","cat"]
while True:
    if(letters[0:7].__eq__("cat")):
        letters.remove("cat")
        print(letters)
```

I get this error

```
['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat'] ['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat', 'cat'] ['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat'] ['dog', '3', 'gorilla']
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/HARISH G/PycharmProjects/projects/one.py", line 4, in <module> letters.remove("cat")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Can you help me understanding why?

Comment: ['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat']
['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat', 'cat']
['dog', '3', 'gorilla', 'cat']
['dog', '3', 'gorilla']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HARISH G/PycharmProjects/projects/one.py", line 4, in <module>
    letters.remove("cat")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: can you please provide problem statement ?

Comment: What are you trying or indending to do?

Comment: What is the world do you imagine this program does?

Comment: Well, at least I realized that `NotImplemented`, as all objects,  is `True` in boolean context...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, try a good form of loop:

```
letters=["cat","dog","3","gorilla","cat","cat","cat"]
print(letters)
while "cat" in letters:
    letters.remove("cat")
    print(letters)
print("Removed All cats one by one")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the while loop until the count of `cat` is not `0` in the list

```
letters=["cat","dog","3","gorilla","cat","cat","cat"]
while (letters.count("cat")):  # looping till all cat's are removed 
    letters.remove("cat") 
print(letters)
```